# Nagios - Connection refused & Socket timeout

Tags: linux, nagios

I need to monitor windows services(like CPU load, memory usage etc.), so I have installed Nagios monitoring tool. The installation is complete and 'check_nt' plugin is also installed.
Upto this no error is there, but while executing scripts with agent NSClient++ 'Connection refused by host' error still persists.

```
./check_nt -H 10.112.32.78 -p 1248 -v MEMUSE -w 80 -c 90
              Connection refused by host

./check_nt -H 10.112.32.78 -p 1248 -v MEMUSE -w 80 -c 90
              Socket timeout after 10 seconds
```

---

I have verified that nagios is working correctly, as under.

```
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

Nagios Core 3.4.1
Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 05-11-2012
License: GPL

Website: http://www.nagios.org
Reading configuration data...
   Read main config file okay...
Processing object config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/contacts.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/timeperiods.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/templates.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg'...
   Read object config files okay...

Running pre-flight check on configuration data...

Checking services...
    Checked 8 services.
Checking hosts...
    Checked 1 hosts.
Checking host groups...
    Checked 1 host groups.
Checking service groups...
    Checked 0 service groups.
Checking contacts...
    Checked 1 contacts.
Checking contact groups...
    Checked 1 contact groups.
Checking service escalations...
    Checked 0 service escalations.
Checking service dependencies...
    Checked 0 service dependencies.
Checking host escalations...
    Checked 0 host escalations.
Checking host dependencies...
    Checked 0 host dependencies.
Checking commands...
    Checked 24 commands.
Checking time periods...
    Checked 5 time periods.
Checking for circular paths between hosts...
Checking for circular host and service dependencies...
Checking global event handlers...
Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
Checking misc settings...

Total Warnings: 0
Total Errors:   0

Things look okay - No serious problems were detected during the pre-flight check
```

M new to nagios, thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would be great is your provide some details on which version of Windows your are running and settings of NSClient++. 

Often firewall rules became the main reason of such issues, so it worth to check them.

Comment: yes i hv chked firewall is not blocking this, but how do i get to the settings, m new to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The connection is getting blocked either by a firewall or your Nagios server is not in the nsc.ini file in the "allowed hosts" field. Make sure that port is open on your windows firewall, as well as any other net filters in between your Nagios server and your client.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Windows server/host you want to monitor is listening on port 5666 for NRPE and 12489 for NT by issuing this command in Windows cmd :

```
netstat -aon | findstr 5666
netstat -aon | findstr 12489
```

It could be that the Windows Firewall is also denying connections on these ports, have a look at that to.

Also add the ip address of your Nagios Monitoring Server to the allowed_hosts of your NSClient++ configuration file located here :

```
C:\Program Files\NSClient++
```

Also during the installation of NSClient++ there was a check-box for check_nt, make sure you checked that too during installation.

After editting configuration files from NSClient++ make sure you restart the NSClient++ service. (in services.msc or Start>Programs>NSClient++>Stop NSClient++ and then Start>Programs>NSClient++>Start NSClient++)

Answer (score 1):

http://pc-freak.net/blog/monitoring-windows-hosts-with-nagios-on-debian-gnulinux/

Depending on your flavor of linux the commands are easily googled for.

Install necessery nagios debian packages

apt-get install nagios-images nagios-nrpe-plugin nagios-nrpe-server nagios-plugins nagios-plugins-basic nagios-plugins-standard 
nagios3 nagios3-cgi nagios3-common nagios3-core

Answer (score 1):

I just came across an issue with this with centos 7. After a few hours of searching and comparing with other servers on the same network, I was ready to give up

I literally compared the nrpe.cfg between both, definitely had the IP for allowed host, and all plugins were rsync'd, permissions were all the same. One problem I had was telnetting to the nrpe port 5666

telnet working_server_ip 5666
works

telnet not_working_server_ip 5666
connection refused.

Took me a while but I somehow came across the two OS, the one working is centos6, while the other is centos7.

If you are installing nrpe on centos7, make sure you disable the firewall and I am not talking about SELinux

systemctl stop firewalld

and then try again